# What is the Guice equivalent to Spring's lookup method?

Tags: java, guice, guice-3

The Spring lookup method lets you have a method that returns a new instance of an object every time you call it.  I read the Guice user guide and didn't see an obvious way of how to do this.  I'd like to have some code like this:

```
@Inject
private FooInstanceFactory fooInstanceFactory;

//...
    Foo foo = fooInstanceFactory.getNewInstanceOfFoo();
//...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really isn't the Guice way of doing things. You can [inject a `Provider<Foo>`](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/InjectingProviders) and call [`Provider#get()`](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/inject/Provider.html#get%28%29) on it, but the *calling* code shouldn't be concerned with whether or not you're getting a new instance each time. That's for the module's configuration to worry about.

Comment: I (perhaps incorrectly) think of Guice as a way of removing the `new` keyword from my production logic.  If I've got some production logic that's generating a JSON message and has lots of `new JSONObject()`'s in it, I need to be sure that each JSONObject I create is a new instance and not a singleton.  How am I thinking about this the wrong way?

Comment: The place to ensure that each JSONObject is new is in the provider's logic, not in the consumer's logic.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Not sure if I've interpreted your statement correctly.  If `SpecificJSONMessageConstructor` needs build a deeply nested JSON message, doesn't the `SpecificJSONMessageConstructor` need to know that every new JSON object it constructs is a different instance from the previous one?  I don't see how I could write my code in a way that that wouldn't matter.  But if you're *simply* saying the `Provider<JSONObject>` should `return new JSONObject()`, not the `SpecificJSONMessageConstructor`, then I think we're on the same page.

Comment: @tieTYT yes, "the `Provider<JSONObject>` should `return new JSONObject()`" is one way to do it. You don't even need to explicitly implement such a provider with Guice – it can be generated automatically. You just need to configure your Guice module for `JSONObject` injection. If you're using `AbstractModule` (which you probably should), just add this line to the `configure()` method: `bind(JSONObject.class);`

Comment: @MattBall Ooh, that's good to know.  How do I get the provider?  Do I just put `@Inject private Provider<JSONObject> jsonProvider;` in the `SpecificJSONMessageConstructor` after I do that bind in the module?

Comment: Yes. Why don't you go and _try_ it?

Comment: I tried it out.  The `bind(...)` is unnecessary.  You can just inject the provider.

Comment: +1. We can use ProtoType/Singleton/RequestScoped scopes on bean definition for the Object contained in provider to determine in what scope we need the new instance to be created.